# Style transfer in Tensorflow: OOM when allocating tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to run this Tensorflow style transfer implementation - https://github.com/anishathalye/neural-style on Windows (the GPU version), but I am getting this error:

> ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating
>   tensor with shape[64,239400]
>            [[Node: gradients/MatMul_grad/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=true,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](gradients/truediv_2_grad/tuple/control_dependency,
>   Reshape)]]

I am a complete beginner in both Tensorflow and Python so I don't really know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Out Of Memory error. You don't have enough GPU memory to run the deep network for this image.

You have 2 solutions :

1. If you don't care about speed, use the CPU version, because you probably have more CPU memory (RAM) than GPU memory. You set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to disable GPU : `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES= python neural_style.py <content file> --styles <style file> --output <output file>`
2. Process a smaller image. Feeding an image of smaller dimensions can really decrease memory usage. So try downsampling your image before feeding it to the script; you can try multiple sizes to see what's the maximum size you can fit into your GPU memory.

Comment: Thanks. Feeding smaller images helped. I just hoped there would be a nicer solution, like a setting I can change so that the network uses less memory.

Comment: There's no magical setting to decrease memory usage. If you're willing to put a lot of effort into it (e.g., if you're deploying to a product), then see quantization : tensorflow.org/performance/quantization